# C#で遅延実行を書いたがActionをジェネリックで渡す方法がわからない

Tags: c#

こんにちは。

C#で、遅延実行をしようとしています。
ある程度は動いています。

下記のソースを定義しました。

```
public static void WaitExecute(int milliseconds, Action f)
{
    // 指定秒後に処理を実行
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)
    };
    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
    {
        // タイマーの停止
        timer.Stop();
        f();
    };
}

private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // 指定秒後に処理を実行
    WaitExecute(100, () =>
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "デフォルト値";
    });
}
```

このようにして、少しだけ動作を遅らせて動かす仕組みを作ってみました。
comboBoxは単なる例です。
Comboboxで何を選択しても、すぐにデフォルト値に戻るような動きをします。
(実際には特定の項目だけデフォルト値に戻る、
 というような実装をしています)

このときに、この、`WaitExecute`に引数として、引き数なしの`Action`を渡すだけではなく
引き数が任意個数の、たとえば、`Action<string>` や `Action<string, string>`や
`Action<int>` などを渡したいのです。

`WaitExecute`を修正して`Action`を引き渡したときに
ジェネリックとして記載するのだと思うのですが、
そのやり方がわかりません。

検索ワードの工夫も難しくテクニックなどがみつかりませんでした。

ご存知でしたら教えてください。

このようなテクニックがわかるWebサイトなどを
示していただくのも助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action<string>`を実行するには`string`引数が必要ですし、`Action<string, string>`を実行するには２つの`string`引数が必要なわけで、

- `WaitExecute(int milliseconds, Action f)`
- `WaitExecute<T0>(int milliseconds, Action<T0> f, T0 s0)`
- `WaitExecute<T0, T1>(int milliseconds, Action<T0, T1> f, T0 s0, T1 s1)`

と引数ごとに異なるシグネチャになります。C#言語ではこれらをひとつにまとめて記述する機能はないため、適切な検索キーワードもありませんし、見つからないのも当然ではあります。余談ですが、C++言語では[Variadic Templates（可変引数テンプレート）](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/variadic_templates.html)という機能で記述できます。

さてC#言語ではそれぞれのメソッドを記述する必要がありますが、この例であれば実現するほどのメリットがあるか疑問です。

なお単に遅延させるだけであれば[`Task.Delay`メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx)が用意されています。

```
private async void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    comboBox1.Text = "デフォルト値";
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
C++についても、asyncについても、新しい知識でとても役に立ちます。
asyncは簡単にスレッド化できて、すごい機能ですね。
助かりました。動作確認もできました。

Answer (score 1):

シグネチャを

```
void WaitExecute<T>(int milliseconds, Action<T> f, T arg)
```

や

```
void WaitExecute<T1, T2>(int milliseconds, Action<T1, T2> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

として`f()`を`f(arg)`や`f(arg1, arg2)`で置き換え、

```
WaitExecute(ms1, Method1, 10);
WaitExecute(ms2, Method2, "foo", "bar");
```

のように呼び出すメソッドを想定しておられるものと思いますが、引数を`f`を実行するためだけに使用するのであれば、

```
WaitExecute(ms1, () => Method1(10));
WaitExecute(ms2, () => Method2("foo", "bar"));
```

のように`Action`でラップして実行すれば事足りるのでは。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そのとおりのことを考えていましたが、ご指摘のとおりで大丈夫でした。
fooや、bar、が定数じゃなくて変数を代入したいと思い、WaitExecuteの外部から内部に何か引数で渡さなければならないと思い込んでいたのですが、
WaitExecuteの上で宣言した変数でも、ラムダ式の中から見ることができました。今回の件は変数値の排他なども考えなくてよいので、まったく事足りました。ありがとうございます。非常に助かりました。